# Is it possible to ignore an additional "www" with virtual hosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

We have a web server with many virtual hosts following this scheme:

```
www.example.com
sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com
sub3.example.com
sub?.example.com
```

Now some of our more naive customers often try `www.sub3.example.com` resulting in a redirect to `www.example.com`.

Is there a configuration setting to automatically redirect all requests targeted at  `www.sub?.example.com` to `sub?.example.com`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NO idea what server technology yyou talk about....
...but it is possible.

Basically it depends on the server. I know such customers, too ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the ServerAlias directive. You can place that next to ServerName in your VirtualHost block